# How to pack variadic arguments of a template function into an array?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, fold-expression, pack-expansion

How to pack variadic arguments of the function into an array and return it from that function? All the arguments are of the same type.

Here's what I try to do, but it only seems to set the very first element of the array and rest of the elements are zero. So that's no good.

```
template<typename... T>
inline auto CreateArray(const T... t)
{
    constexpr int ELEMENT_COUNT = TotalElementCount(t...);

    return std::array<int, ELEMENT_COUNT>{ (t, ...) };
}
```

So if I run the following code:

```
    auto new_array = CreateArray(1, 2, 3, 4);

    for (auto x : new_array)
        std::cout << std::dec << x << std::endl;
```

I'll get the result:

```
4
0
0
0
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: `(t, ...)` produces a single value after evaluating comma operator for the pack. `return std::array{t...};` is sufficient

Comment: @user7860670. Ah. That works. It seems I tried it in a too complicated way.

Comment: This function works kinda like https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array which was removed after becoming useless because `std::array` got a deduction guide.

Comment: Don't edit the question to say "Solved". If you have a good enough solution to share, answer your own question instead.

Comment: Whatever you wrote for `TotalElementCount` is not necessary. You just need `sizeof...(T)`.

Comment: i removed the answer from your question. You can still access it here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77841279/revisions. You can copy it to the answer section to answer your own question

Comment: @user7860670, what about if I at some point wanted to have functions as parameters instead of scalar values? How would those function be run to get their results into that same array? i.e. "return std::array<int, ELEMENT_COUNT>{ my_function(parameter)... };"

Comment: please also do not add an "ADDITIONAL QUESTION" here. You can open a new question. There should be one question per quesiton. Anyhow, its not clear what the problem is with the code. Did you try to compile and run it ? What happened when you did?

Comment: That is why we really need to clear up the understanding here. `(parameter,...)` is a **fold expression**, the comma is an **operator**. `{parameter...}` on the other hand expands to `{parameter1, parameter2, ...}` where the comma is a **separator**. Rule of thumb: if you don't need a comma operator(you seldom do), don't use the form with parenthesis and comma. We can tell you the fix for specific cases, but you need to understand the difference to write correct code yourself and not to make the same mistake again. Don't try and error.

Comment: for your additional detail the fix is exactly the same. That and one typo and the code works as is: https://godbolt.org/z/5ahTPY3zG

Comment: @WeijunZhou why not turn this into an answer. The mistake is a typo, but as you correctly state that typo is symptom of a misunderstanding that is actaully deeper than just making a typo

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai
I removed the additional question/information part, as the method actually seems to work well for functions as parameters as well. So there was no need for me to actually request that extra detail for the information.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Done, but seems it took me too long~

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was refering to the close votes. At the time of my comment I think there was already one that voted to close as typo and I can understand where they come from even though I dont agree with them

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Aha, oki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `TotalElementCount(t...);` should be just `sizeof...(t)` and the result is not an `int` but a `std::size_t`. You can use `auto` to get the correct type automatically.
- `(t, ...)` is a fold over the comma operator. The comma operator discards results of the left operands and leaves only the rightmost operand. Compare with:

  ```
  std::cout << (1,2,3,4) << '\n'; // prints 4
  ```

What you want here is not a fold expression but a pack expansion:

```cpp
template <typename... T>
inline auto CreateArray(const T... t) {
    constexpr auto ELEMENT_COUNT = sizeof...(t);

    return std::array<int, ELEMENT_COUNT>{t...};
//                                       ^^^^^^
}
```

A perfect forwarding version:

```cpp
template <typename... T>
inline auto CreateArray(T&&... t) {
    constexpr auto ELEMENT_COUNT = sizeof...(t);

    return std::array<int, ELEMENT_COUNT>{std::forward<T>(t)...};
}
```

You may also want to replace the value type `int` in the array with `std::common_type_t<T...>` to allow for the creation of non-`int` arrays.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the commands, the fix for your original question is simple,

```
return std::array{t...};
```

The fix for your (now removed) "additional detail" is also basically just the same. However, as I said in the comment, you really need to understand the difference between these two very similar syntax to understand what is wrong.

First, you need to understand that the (unquoted, of course) comma in C++ has two major roles: as a **separator**, and as an **operator**. The comma operator in `a,b` means evaluate `a` first, then evaluate `b`. It is not used very often and you should be relatively easy to tell it when you meet one. Most of the comma you see are separators. This include the commas in parameter and argument lists (`f(int,int)` , `f(a,b)`, `template <typename, typename>`, `f<1,2>()` ), as well as braced-init-lists (`std::array{1,2,3}`).

The correct syntax here, `std::array{t...}`, is called **pack expansion** and is introduced in C++11, it expands an expression to a list of expressions separated by the comma **separator**. For example, if `t` is a pack containing `t1` and `t2`, `f(t)...` expands to `f(t1),f(t2)`, while `t(f)` expands to `t1(f),t2(f)`. The commas here are **separators**. Pack expansion is what you need most of the time.

That means in all the cases mentioned as examples for comma separators, you should use pack expansion,

```
void f(T...); //declaration of variadic function
f(t...); //calling variadic function
template <typename...> class C{}; //template class with variadic type parameters
f<t...>(); //Calling function with explicit variadic template parameters
std::array{t...}; //Braced-init-list
```

and many more.

Your syntax here, `(t,...)` used as an expression, is a **fold expression** introduced in C++17. For the same `t` as the previous example, It expands to `(t1, t2)`, where the comma is an **operator**, meaning `t1` gets evaluated, and then `t2`, but in the end, you only get **a single** expression, unlike **a list of** expressions in the previous case. If you are not familiar with template meta programming, you seldom need to use fold expression with the comma separator. This type of expression is often used for tricks where the side-effect of each expression is of major interest. An example is:

```
(logging_func(t),...)
```

This will log each parameter in the parameter pack. The final result of the expression is discarded.

It is now very clear that what you need is pack expansion (which is also what you need in most cases) not fold expression, and the fix is presented above.